# Use variables in GitLab CI/CD yaml file

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml

My .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe'
  SOLUTION_FOLDER: CrmServices
  CONFUGURATION: Debug

stages:
  - build

build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - '"$NUGET_PATH" restore $SOLUTION_FOLDER'
    - '"$MSBUILD_PATH" $SOLUTION_FOLDER /p:Configuration=$CONFUGURATION /clp:ErrorsOnly'
```

In Ci/CD log I see error

```
+ $NUGET_PATH restore $SOLUTION_FOLDER
+             ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'restore' in expression or statement.
```

I try to remove single quotes in *variable* section.

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: C:\Nuget\nuget.exe
  MSBUILD_PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe
```

This has not changed anything.
I try to remove single quotes in *script* section.

```
script:
    - $NUGET_PATH restore $SOLUTION_FOLDER
```

This has not changed anything.

```
script:
    - "$NUGET_PATH" restore "$SOLUTION_FOLDER"
```

This leads to an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've carefully quoted out the whole script, remove the single quotes.

Comment: Removing quotes in the variables section doesn't change anything.
Removing quotes in the script section leads to an error "did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection".

Comment: Could you [edit] to show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have written like this:

```
"$env:NUGET_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `$MSBUILD_PATH` by `%MSBUILD_PATH%`. I guess you are using a Windows runner, not a Linux one.